# Access HTML element from express js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I've created the sample app using express js to upload the file on the local path.

**app.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);
    const upload = require("express-fileupload");

    app.use(upload());

    console.log("Server Started");

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
    )

    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.files) {
        //console.log(req.files);
        const file = req.files.filename;
        const filename = file.name;

        file.mv("./upload/" + filename, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("error occured");
        }
        else {
            res.send("Done");
        }
        })
    }
    })
```

**index.html**

```
    <div>
    <h1 style="align-content: center">Upload your file here!</h1>
    </div>
    <div style=" background-color: white;
                padding:64px;
                display:flex;
                align-items:flex-start;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                box-shadow:  0 15px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0 20px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
                box-sizing:border-box">

    <form label="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <label> Enter reference</label>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <br><br>
        <input type="file" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
    </div>
```

I need the help to access the text content entered on the input type = "text" from the app.js file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NodeJS is serverside, which means there is no html to be accessed like in client side javascript. If you want to access data stored in your dom you have to send it to the server from the client.

Comment: @CodeSpirit — That's what the `<form>` in the HTML does.

Comment: @Quentin - In my case, could you please let me  know how I can access the type = "text" on the app.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give a `name` attribute to the `type=text` field. Then you can access the field using the name. Suppose you have set it as `<input type="text" name="user_input"></input>`. Now from your `app.post` you can access it as `req.body.user_input`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems.

## You aren't sending the data

Only form controls with names can be successful controls. *Something* has to equal the value typed in.

Give the input a name:

```
<input type="text" name="foo">
```

## You aren't looking for the data

Then the body parser you are using (Busboy, wrapped in express-fileupload) will populate the `req.body` object so you can access it via `req.body.foo`.

## Asides

- The end tag for `<input>` elements is forbidden in HTML. Use a validator: https://validator.nu/
- Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless. See [this guide](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)